# Is it possible to install a VPN server on win 10 so all people in this vpn can play old game (HOMM3) like in local network?

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I  and my friends (total three people) want to play the old game HOMM3 (Heroes of Might and Magic -- death shadow version ) .

because we are in different place, so I want try to do this:

```
  I  have two PC , one is win10 laptop , another is windows xp, they all in my home .

  install a VPN server on my win10 laptop ,then allow my xp machine and my two friends connect to this server. if success , these three machine are just like in local network environment then can play together using IPX protocol,  right  ?
```

If anyone have try this before , could you tell me If it is possible , the most not-understand for me is :  once a person connect to this VPN ,his machine will have two IP right ?  one is his local router given IP , and one is my VPN server given IP , How I  know HOMM3 decide to use which IP to connect other player ?

regards
liuyang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are even easier solution for this.
Try [Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net). You just install it on every PC, create a server, join and you all can play like in local network.

Comment: yes, while I  search solution on google , I also find someone suggest Hamachi , but compare with use framework or tools , I prefer to do it step by step myself , I think maybe this looks more like a geek (although I am not yet ) . maybe when I try fail , I will choose Hamachi or other tools .